# How to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of higher-order tensors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensors, tensor-rank

I'm currently looking a way to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a tensor which has a higher order than 2.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: How do you define an eigenvector for a higher-order tensor? It takes as “input” more than one vector/covector.